How to add configuration from a file in a NuGet package into the config for the project when it is imported?
We have a NuGet package that we have created. The goal of which is to provide common logging and telemetry reporting to each project we import it into. We also want to make this pretty much invisible to the project developers. To that end we have included configuration in the NuGet package for the logging and telemetry. What we are trying to do is add that configuration to the project configuration when the NuGet package is imported.
Not even sure if this makes sense but I hope I'm at least being clear about what we're trying to accomplish.
Any thoughts, or suggestions most gratefully accepted.
We have tried adding configuration to the NuGet config file but that doesn't seem to get us anywhere.
